# Unity pause text display in between stanzas wait for user input

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine

I have a script that currently displays dialogue text letter by letter. Currently it rolls through each string of text in my _stanzas array without pausing. I would like to change this script so that it requires the user to press "Z" on their keyboard before the script begins to print the next block of text from _stanzas. I cant seem to figure it out...here is my code.

using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

```
public class Text : MonoBehaviour {


public float LetterPause = 0.1f;
public GameObject text;
public GameObject box;
public GameObject name;
    private bool _textFinished;
    private int _textIndex;
    private string[] _stanzas;
int tracker;

    public void Start()
    {
    if (Application.loadedLevel == 1) {
                    _stanzas = new [] {
                            " It’s Terrence’s hat... ",
                            "He always was one to lose track of the" + "\n" + "material objects in life," + "\n" + "but to hold onto the immaterial forever.",
                            "I’ll carry it for him" + "\n" + "until I find him. "
                    };
            }


        _textFinished = true;
        _textIndex = -1;
    tracker = _textIndex;
    }

public void Update()
{   

    if (_textFinished)
    {
        if (_textIndex++ >= (_stanzas.Length - 1))
        {
            _textFinished = false;
            text.SetActive(false);
            box.SetActive(false);
            name.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (_textFinished){
                SetText(_stanzas[_textIndex]);}
    }
}

    private IEnumerator TypeText(float waitTime, string text)
    {
        _textFinished = false;

        guiText.text = "";

        foreach (var letter in text)
        {
            guiText.text += letter;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
        }

        _textFinished = true;
    }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        StartCoroutine(TypeText(LetterPause, text));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (_textFinished)
```

to

```
if (_textFinished && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) || _textIndex < 0))
```